# Inject function in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, jasmine

I am unit testing angularjs controller with jasmine, karma.... the test sample looks like this:

```
     beforeEach(inject(function(_$rootScope_, _$controller_){
    $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
    $scope = $rootScope.$new();
    $controller = _$controller_;
    $controller('AboutController', {'$rootScope' : $rootScope, '$scope': $scope});
}));
```

Here, I am confused how did jasmine come to know about the inject function? Is it the same function object as angular's Injector.inject()... I am surprised, the method is available outside Angular namespace... and what does the *$controller* variable injected into function do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the `inject` function is part of the [Angular Mocks package (ngMock)](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock).  You probably added this to your karma.conf.js file in order to get the jasmine tests configured.  So, this way of injecting is *not* available in production Angular code, it is only used for unit testing.

That package adds `inject` to the window object (global) as a convenience during testing.

From the docs:

> NOTE: This function is also published on window for easy access.

For more information [here is the documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/function/angular.mock.inject).

As for the second question: The `$controller` service allows you to initialize a named controller (`'AboutController'` in your example) and pass in it's dependencies.  Getting a handle on `$scope` is often necessary when testing controllers.